# NavigationBar not appearing in second view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

i am working on iPhone app.. i am using navigation controller, but the when i am going to the second view controller i.e. to the child view controller, the navigation bar is not appearing i had tried all the solutions around. Changing the property from translucent to inferred, vice-versa, tried doing it in code in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, viewWillAppear, everything..

Need some help..

In simulator it is showing and working perfectly but in device it isn't. I am using iphone 4s.

Check screenshot at below location:

http://postimg.org/image/y3nzz6t79/

I wanted to use below existing Back functionality - hence the transitions:

http://postimg.org/image/r2q34a4sr/

Comment: please share your code of navigation bar here for find out actually error.

Comment: I used storyboard to do the transitions.
Step1: Created a Navigation Controller and put custom changes to the existing navigation bar (color etc.)
Step 2: Created the parent view controller having "rootViewController" (show) segue from navigation controller - Navigation Bar gets displayed here.
Step 3: Created the child view controller with show segue from parent view controller - Navigation Bar gets displayed when code runs on simulator but not on device (iPhone 4s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to embed your second view controller with Navigation Controller.

Set Top bar property to Opaque

Add this code in ViewDidAppear

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```